# Generating Maze using DFS Algorithm

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, maze

Here is pseudo code for DFS Algorithm
http://www.mazeworks.com/mazegen/mazetut/index.htm

create a CellStack (LIFO) to hold a list of cell locations
set TotalCells = number of cells in grid
choose a cell at random and call it CurrentCell
set VisitedCells = 1

while VisitedCells < TotalCells 
find all neighbors of CurrentCell with all walls intact
if one or more found 
choose one at random
knock down the wall between it and CurrentCell
push CurrentCell location on the CellStack
make the new cell CurrentCell
add 1 to VisitedCells

else

pop the most recent cell entry off the CellStack
make it CurrentCell

endIf
endWhile

My smalltalk code

```
 Maze>>initialize
   |sampleCell width height n sample |

super initialize.
self borderWidth: 0.   
sampleCell := VisibleSquare  new.  
width := sampleCell width.
height := sampleCell  height.
self bounds: (5@5 extent: ((width + n) @ (height + n)) + (2 * self borderWidth)).
visitedcell :=0.
cells := Matrix rows: 8 columns: 7 tabulate: [:i :j |  self newCellAt: i at:j].
```

Here is other method.

```
Maze>>newCellAt:i at:j
  |c|
   celltotal:= 8*7.
[(visitedcell< celltotal)] whileTrue:
["Im stuck with selecting cells next to current cell to make it as
Invisible square" 
"else do this"
c := VisibleSquare new.
origin := self innerBounds origin.
self addMorphBack:  c.
c position: ((i - 1) * c width) @ ((j - 1) * c height) + origin. 
 ^ c
```

I have 2 classes one as Visiblesquare is nothing but red square and other as Invisiblesquare which is empty square [image]

Comment: so, what is the question?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem lies in using `rows:columns:tabulate:` to fill in the matrix, since you are not using the depth-first approach described in the algorithm (and it seems that you are also looping again for each cell; I don't really follow what it is supposed to do this :( ). From my POV you should:

1. Fill in the matrix in the `initialize` method, setting all the squares of the matrix to a new instance of `VisibleSquare` (each instance should at least hold its position and/or a reference to its neighbors, so that you can later ask for a cell's neighbors).
2. Add a new line (like `self arrangeWalls`) at the end of the `initialize` method that implements the algorithm as described in the article.

HTH

Comment: I think you are right it made whole process complicated for me , I am using TiledMorph class now its easy to Implement a maze with that